# Using SQL Server CLR procedure to retrieve data via Exact Target web services

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, webservices

I have written a basic c# program that calls the ExactTarget webservice and updates a subscriber list and that all worked fine.  Then I took the class and created a CLR stored procedure and embedded it into my SQL Server (2008 R2).  However, when I try to call the stored procedure, I get the following error:  **System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error in serializing body of message RetrieveRequest1.**  I have Googled that message multiple times and tried everything that Microsoft and others have said would fix the problem but nothing is working.  Does anyone have experience creating a SQL CLR procedure that calls the Exact Target Webservice?

Comment: This post seems to have lots of info regarding this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452/error-serializing-string-in-webservice-call  When you say you have tried everything, I assume this came up and none of the solutions have solved the issue?  This doesn't seem like it's really an ET issue, but a CLR issue.

Comment: Correct.  There is plenty of information on the web about this CLR serialization issue and how to resolve it and I tried all the suggestions.  I was hoping that someone had got it to work with the Exact Target webservice

Comment: I've asked around to see if anyone ha S suggestions,  but not something I've done.  Hopefully it will turn up some results.

Answer (score 1):

I found some information here that may be useful.  It appears that this is an issue with newer versions of Visual Studio.  The 2nd answer on this post has 3 steps that you may want to try if you're using a version of VS more recent than VS2010.  Let me know if this helps!

[Calling WebService from CLR Stored Procedure](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/390e81b6-7d4d-4132-bd8d-5ead822b778a/sql-clr-stored-procedure-calling-webservice-serialization-error?forum=sqlnetfx)

Comment: I tried these things but still no luck.  We have decided not to spend any more time on trying to get this to work.